# Interface Implementing with interface property

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have a Class, that has one property that is another interface,
like the example below:

```
public interface ICar
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    ICarInfo Info { get; set; }
}

public interface ICarInfo
{
    Motor Motor { get; set; }
    Wheels Wheels { get; set; }
    String Category{ get; set; }
}
```

And two implementations for the ICarInfo:

```
public Class SUVInfo : ICarInfo
{
    Motor Motor { get; set; } = new Motor("SUV");
    Wheels Wheels { get; set; } = new Wheels("SUV");
    String Category{ get; set; } = "SUV";
}

public Class CompactInfo : ICarInfo
{
    Motor Motor { get; set; } = new Motor("Compact");
    Wheels Wheels { get; set; } = new Wheels("Compact");
    String Category{ get; set; } = "Compact";
}
```

I can't implement one class of ICar, using the implementation of ICarInfo, like the example:

```
 public Class SUV : ICar
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    SUVInfo Info { get; set; }
}
```

SUVInfo is a ICarInfo, but the following error appears:

> 'SUV' does not implement interface member 'ICar.Info'. 'SUV.Info'
>   cannot implement 'ICar.Info' because it does not have the matching
>   return type of 'ICarInfo'.

Comment: Add an explicit implementation of the `ICar.Info` property.

Comment: Your model seem to violate [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Can you just add `ICarInfo ICar.Info { get; set; }` to your class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having different classes for `ICarInfo` that solely differ in their values of the properties, you can just use a single class and pass those values to its constructor:

```
public class CarInfo : ICarInfo {
    Motor Motor { get; set; }
    Wheels Wheels { get; set; }
    String Category{ get; set; }

    public CarInfo(Motor motor, Wheels wheels, string category)
    {
        this.Motor = motor;
        this.Wheels = wheels;
        this.Category = category;
    }
}
```

This way you don´t need to mess up with different types at all:

```
public Class SUV : ICar
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    ICarInfo Info { get; set; } = new CarInfo(new Motor("SUV"), new Wheels("SUV"), "SUV");
}
```

You can also use generics, if you really want different classes:

```
public interface ICar<T> where T: ICarInfo
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    T Info { get; set; }
}

public interface ICarInfo
{
    Motor Motor { get; set; }
    Wheels Wheels { get; set; }
    String Category{ get; set; }
}
public Class SUVInfo : ICarInfo
{
    Motor Motor { get; set; } = new Motor("SUV");
    Wheels Wheels { get; set; } = new Wheels("SUV");
    String Category{ get; set; } = "SUV";
}

public Class SUV : ICar<SUVInfo>
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    SUVInfo Info { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your class SUV implements the interface ICar, it has to implement every property and function which is declared in that interface. So as your ICar looks like this:

```
interface ICar
{
   int ID { get; set; }
   ICarInfo Info { get; set; }
}
```

your SUV has to look like this (at minimum):

```
class SUV : ICar
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICarInfo Info { get; set; }
}
```

of course you can add any other property or function to your SUV class.

I think what you expected was some kind of inheritance: As the SUVInfo already implements ICarInfo interface you can just declare an property of type SUVInfo. But Interface implementation in C# does not work like this.